# GestureDetector in ListView not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show user avatars in list view and navigate to chat page on click event.

```
Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: matches!.length > 0
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: matches!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print("go to chat page");
                            
                          },
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: secondryColor,
                            radius: 35.0,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: matches?[index].imageUrl[0] ?? '',
                                useOldImageOnUrlChange: true,
                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                    const CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                                  radius: 15,
                                ),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                    const Icon(Icons.error),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  : const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "No match found",
                        style: TextStyle(color: secondryColor, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
```

I tried to use InkWell that didn't work either. I used TextButton it works but only on the top-outside of the avatar.

Comment: It is working in my case. Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

trying adding the gesture ScrollBehavior

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}

return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
)
```